# bindingRedirect in Asp.net vNext

Tags: asp.net-core

How can I achieve a binding redirect in asp.net vnext? Before I would have configured the bindingRedirect using xml in the web.config file, but I can find how to to this in the Project.json

https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Project.json-file

Comment: I too am seeing this problem, but with Autofac   Assuming assembly reference 'Autofac, Version=3.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da' used by 'Autofac.Extras.Attributed' matches identity 'Autofac, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da' of 'Autofac', you may need to supply runtime policy

Answer (score 1):

Binding redirects are not needed in ASP.NET 5. The loader in ASP.NET 5 will automatically load the correct DLL based on project references and the available NuGet and project references.

Or, if you have a case that doesn't work, please provide more details.

Comment: What I am seeing is a compiler warning.
 Warning CS1701 Assuming assembly reference 'Castle.Windsor, Version=2.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc' used by 'CommonServiceLocator.WindsorAdapter' matches identity 'Castle.Windsor, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc' of 'Castle.Windsor', you may need to supply runtime policy WebApplication2.ASP.NET 5.0 MediatRInstaller.cs 16

Comment: Can you update the question showing what you tried and what the errors were?

Comment: I'd also like to know how to get rid of this warning, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

According to David Fowler from the ASPNET team, binding redirects are gone and not coming back.  I created a GitHub issue and he thinks this needs to be done at the Roslyn level (basically, don't output this warning anymore).

https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/407