# What do I do when ASP.NET 5 (vNext) can't redirect bindings?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, structuremap, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, structuremap3

I am just getting my feet wet with MVC 6. I installed VS 2015 and with the default `ASP.NET 5 preview` `MVC Web Application` template everything runs fine under local IIS.

I then tried to switch out the Default DI container with `StructureMap` following [these instructions](http://josephwoodward.co.uk/2015/07/setting-up-structuremap-3-in-asp-net-mvc-6-vnext/) exactly (note it is a very recent article). The only thing is I had to figure out the namespaces to import myself (since the author neglected to include them) and this is what I included.

I put the `StructureMapRegistration` class and all related classes into a single file, and here are the usings.

```
using Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection;
using StructureMap;
using StructureMap.Configuration.DSL.Expressions;
```

I added the following usings to the `Startup.cs` file.

```
using StructureMap;
using StructureMap.Graph;
using System.Reflection;
```

And I made the following edit to the `Startup.cs` file.

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add Entity Framework services to the services container.
    services.AddEntityFramework()
        .AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

    // Add Identity services to the services container.
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    // Configure the options for the authentication middleware.
    // You can add options for Google, Twitter and other middleware as shown below.
    // For more information see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715
    services.Configure<FacebookAuthenticationOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
        options.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];
    });

    services.Configure<MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:MicrosoftAccount:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:MicrosoftAccount:ClientSecret"];
    });

    // Add MVC services to the services container.
    services.AddMvc();

    //// Uncomment the following line to add Web API services which makes it easier to port Web API 2 controllers.
    //// You will also need to add the Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim package to the 'dependencies' section of project.json.
    //// services.AddWebApiConventions();

    //// Register application services.
    //services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
    //services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();

    var container = new Container();
    container.Configure(x =>
    {
        x.Scan(scanning =>
        {
            scanning.Assembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            scanning.TheCallingAssembly();
            scanning.WithDefaultConventions();
        });

        //x.AddRegistry<WebsiteRegistry>();
    });

    // Our framework extension point
    container.Populate(services);
}
```

> Literally, the ***only*** things I have changed from the default template are the above code changes and installing `StructureMap` 3.1.6.186.

The using statements suppress all of the design time compilation errors, but when I build, I get several other errors.

> Error CS0012  The type 'Action<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'. TestDI3.DNX Core 5.0    f:\Users\Shad\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestDI3\src\TestDI3\Services\StructureMapRegistration.cs    32
>
> Error CS0012  The type 'IDisposable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'.  TestDI3.DNX Core 5.0    f:\Users\Shad\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestDI3\src\TestDI3\Services\StructureMapRegistration.cs    32
>
> Error CS0012  The type 'Func<,>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'.  TestDI3.DNX Core 5.0    f:\Users\Shad\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestDI3\src\TestDI3\Services\StructureMapRegistration.cs    59
>
> Error CS0012  The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'.   TestDI3.DNX Core 5.0    f:\Users\Shad\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestDI3\src\TestDI3\Services\StructureMapRegistration.cs    59
>
> Error CS0012  The type 'Type' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'. TestDI3.DNX Core 5.0    f:\Users\Shad\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestDI3\src\TestDI3\Services\StructureMapRegistration.cs    63
>
> Error CS0012  The type 'Expression<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'.  TestDI3.DNX Core 5.0    f:\Users\Shad\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestDI3\src\TestDI3\Services\StructureMapRegistration.cs    63
>
> Error CS0012  The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'.   TestDI3.DNX Core 5.0    f:\Users\Shad\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestDI3\src\TestDI3\Services\StructureMapRegistration.cs    63
>
> Error CS0012  The type 'Type' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'. TestDI3.DNX Core 5.0    f:\Users\Shad\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestDI3\src\TestDI3\Services\StructureMapRegistration.cs    67
>
> Error CS0012  The type 'Expression<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'.  TestDI3.DNX Core 5.0    f:\Users\Shad\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestDI3\src\TestDI3\Services\StructureMapRegistration.cs    67
>
> Error CS0012  The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'.   TestDI3.DNX Core 5.0    f:\Users\Shad\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestDI3\src\TestDI3\Services\StructureMapRegistration.cs    67
>
> Error CS0012  The type 'Type' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'. TestDI3.DNX Core 5.0    f:\Users\Shad\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestDI3\src\TestDI3\Services\StructureMapRegistration.cs    89
>
> Error CS0012  The type 'IDisposable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'.  TestDI3.DNX Core 5.0    f:\Users\Shad\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestDI3\src\TestDI3\Services\StructureMapRegistration.cs    89
>
> Error CS0411  The type arguments for method 'IContainer.GetInstance(string)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.  TestDI3.DNX Core 5.0    f:\Users\Shad\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestDI3\src\TestDI3\Services\StructureMapRegistration.cs    89
>
> Error CS0012  The type 'IDisposable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'.  TestDI3.DNX Core 5.0    f:\Users\Shad\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestDI3\src\TestDI3\Services\StructureMapRegistration.cs    107
>
> Error CS0012  The type 'IDisposable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'.  TestDI3.DNX Core 5.0    f:\Users\Shad\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestDI3\src\TestDI3\Services\StructureMapRegistration.cs    107
>
> Error CS0012  The type 'IDisposable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'.  TestDI3.DNX Core 5.0    f:\Users\Shad\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestDI3\src\TestDI3\Services\StructureMapRegistration.cs    120
>
> Error CS1061  'IContainer' does not contain a definition for 'Dispose' and no extension method 'Dispose' accepting a first argument of type 'IContainer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) TestDI3.DNX Core 5.0    f:\Users\Shad\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestDI3\src\TestDI3\Services\StructureMapRegistration.cs    120
>
> Error CS0012  The type 'Action<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'. TestDI3.DNX Core 5.0    f:\Users\Shad\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestDI3\src\TestDI3\Startup.cs  94
>
> Error CS0012  The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'.   TestDI3.DNX Core 5.0    f:\Users\Shad\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestDI3\src\TestDI3\Startup.cs  94
>
> Error CS0012  The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'.   TestDI3.DNX Core 5.0    f:\Users\Shad\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestDI3\src\TestDI3\Startup.cs  107
>
> Error CS0012  The type 'IDisposable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'.  TestDI3.DNX Core 5.0    f:\Users\Shad\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestDI3\src\TestDI3\Startup.cs  107
>
> Error CS0012  The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'.   TestDI3.DNX Core 5.0    f:\Users\Shad\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestDI3\src\TestDI3\Startup.cs  107

The error indicates where the problem is - I need a reference to mscorlib 2.0.5.0. But I am already referencing mscorlib 4.0.0.0 in the project.

At this point in ASP.NET < 5, the next step would typically be to add some binding redirects to the `<bindingRedirect>` section of the web.config file. However, after searching for how to do this in ASP.NET 5, I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27987717/bindingredirect-in-asp-net-vnext) which indicates that binding redirection is supposed to be "totally automatic".

So is this a bug, or is there some step in my configuration that I missed that is resulting in this error?

## Configuration

> DNX 1.0.0-beta5
>
> .NET Framework
>
> x86
>
> IIS Express

### project.json

```
{
    "webroot": "wwwroot",
    "userSecretsId": "aspnet5-TestDI3-1665343b-5aa5-4d08-8596-a1a536223a19",
    "version": "1.0.0-*",

    "dependencies": {
        "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta5",
        "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta5",
        "structuremap": "3.1.6.186"
    },

    "commands": {
        "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini",
        "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": { },
        "dnxcore50": { }
    },

    "exclude": [
        "wwwroot",
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components"
    ],
    "publishExclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "**.xproj",
        "**.user",
        "**.vspscc"
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your project.json look like and is this happening in IIS Express or IIS?

Comment: @opiants - added to my answer. I have changed nothing from the default template except for the above code changes and adding StructureMap 3.1.6.186 as a dependency. The project doesn't even compile so I am pretty certain this has nothing to do with IIS Express.

Comment: Have no experience with StructureMap itself but could it be that it doesn't support .NET Core yet? Even early-adopter DI containers are still in its very early stages. Anyway, try removing `dnxcore50` in your `frameworks` in `projects.json` and see if it compiles or maybe try [this nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StructureMap.Dnx/) instead or try both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to opiants, the problem appears to be related to the fact that the `dnxcore50` framework was included in the project.

```
"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
}
```

Removing it solved the issue.

```
"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }
}
```

Comment: Depending on your requirements, you might want to actually leave that in there. Did you try the [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StructureMap.Dnx/) though?