# Does a DNX MVC 6 Website required both references groups DNX 4.5.1 and DNX Core 5.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If the web site is targeting only DNX Core on Azure can the DNX 4.5.1 references be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

In fact, if your code isn't compatible with both frameworks [you won't be able to compile until one of them is removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32156615/what-do-i-do-when-asp-net-5-vnext-cant-redirect-bindings).