# Resolving references in ASP.Net 5, "IDisposable is ... not referenced"

Tags: neo4j, asp.net-core, portable-class-library, asp.net5

I did the following:

- Created a new Web.Api project: "WFW3". I used the "Web API" template
  under **ASP.Net 5**.
- I created a new class library, "Foo.Domain", again using **ASP.Net
  5**.
- I added a reference to it from the API project.
- I installed **Neo4j.Driver** (a portable class library) from Nuget into the Foo.Domain project. [Neo4j-NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Neo4j.Driver/1.0.0)

Everything seemed fine to this point. Everything compiled, though it did nothing.

In Foo.Domain I created a class with a method that referenced the GraphDatabase class inside a 'using' statment. This is where it broke.

I received this error message (and others like it):

> The type 'IDisposable' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to 
>       assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.  Foo.Domain..NET Framework
>   4.5.1 C:\dev\WFW3\src\Foo.Domain\FooRepository.cs

My understanding is that binding redirects are not available in ASP.Net 5. Is this correct? How can I solve this issue not referencing the correct version of System.Runtime?
Items found in System.Runtime *are* available to me. It seems to be looking for an older version of the System.Runtime from within the Neo4j.Driver.V1 assembly. I tried the solution found here ([Nathan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16228029/343468)), but then it started complaining that I was trying to import two different types of the Runtime library and I needed to remove one. But which one should I remove, and how?

API project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Foo.Domain": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet": "1.0.0-rc1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

Foo.Domain project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Foo.Domain": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet": "1.0.0-rc1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

FooRepository code (in Foo.Domain):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Neo4j.Driver.V1;

namespace Foo.Domain
{
   public class FooRepository: IFooRepository
    {

        public Foo GetById(string Id)
        {
            // The next lines inside the 'using' are getting the error.
            using (var driver = GraphDatabase.Driver("http://localhost:7474/"))
            using (var session = driver.Session())
            {
                var result = session.Run("CREATE (n) RETURN n");
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found my solution. In addition to removing the 'dnxcore50' framework from the root, web.api library as @Nkosi suggested, I needed to add a '**frameworkAssemblies**' section in my class library.
The following change to the 'Foo.Domain' library got the solution compiling and behaving as expected.

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "Foo.Domain Class Library",
  "authors": [ "Malcolm" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.10.0"
      }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Neo4j.Driver": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Referencing this similar question : [What do I do when ASP.NET 5 (vNext) can't redirect bindings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32156615/what-do-i-do-when-asp-net-5-vnext-cant-redirect-bindings)

The problem in that question appeared to be related to the fact that the `dnxcore50` framework was included in the project.

```
"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
}
```

and removing it solved the issue.

```
"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }
}
```

This worked in their case and should also work for you. I believe you are getting this because of omitting dependencies required by the Core CLR (dnxcore50) framework as referenced here:

**[Frameworks](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Project.json-file#frameworks)**

> This snippet will build for Desktop (dnx451) or Core CLR (dnxcore50).
>   **Core CLR has many extra dependencies as the packages that make up the
>   BCL need to be referenced**...

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {},
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Collections": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.Collections.Concurrent": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.ComponentModel": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.Reflection": "4.0.10.0",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.20.0",
        "System.Runtime.InteropServices": "4.0.10.0",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.Threading.Tasks": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which is why when it was removed from the previous question the project worked. Most of the other posts I saw related to this issue also suggested removing `dnxcore50`

You can also look at this for a better understanding...

**[Framework-specific dependencies](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/dnx/projects.html#framework-specific-dependencies)**

> You can also add dependencies for a particular framework like this:

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "dnxcore50":{
      "dependencies":{
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    },
    "dnx451":{}
  }
}
```

> In the above example, the `System.Runtime` dependency is only needed for
>   the *dnxcore50* target, not *dnx451*. It is often the case that you will
>   have extra dependencies on Core CLR, because there are packages that
>   you need to depend on in Core CLR that are part of .NET 4.5.x.

### **Note**

> While it is technically true that you do not need the `System.Runtime`
>   package on .NET 4.5.1, it also doesn’t matter if you add it as a top
>   level dependency. Each of the `System.*` packages will work as a top
>   level dependency. So, you don’t always have to have this separation.
>   You could add `System.Runtime` as a top level dependency and it will not
>   impact your application when on .NET 4.5.1.

Additional reference material:

[Diagnosing dependency issues with ASP.NET 5](http://davidfowl.com/diagnosing-dependency-issues-with-asp-net-5/)

[How can I diagnose missing dependencies (or other loader failures) in dnx?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29161703/5233410)

Comment: Your solution by itself did not work. I found that removing the dnxcore50 was required in my solution, but was not the only thing required, given the addition of the Neo4j.Driver dependency.

Comment: Glad it helped you find a solution to your issue. If my answer was useful, you can up-vote it. Thanks.